# Redirect based on Accept-Language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to honor the web browser's list of language preferences. Supported languages are English and French. For example: http_accept_language="jp-JP;fr;en-US;en" redirects to a directory called /French/. How can I do this with rewrite rules in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t use mod_rewrite for this but a more powerful language. Because *Accept-Language* is a list of weighted values (see [quality value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.9)) and the occurrence of one of the identifiers does not mean that it’s preferred over another value (especially `q=0` means not acceptable at all).

As already said, use a more powerful language than mod_rewrite, parse the list of value and find the best match of preferred options and available options.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the goal would be to match with the first language in priority order set up in the browser. I guess the english version would be the default version and the french version for people living in Belgium, Canada, Switzerland. So, i would suggest to implement the following: It will return french if it finds french somewhere first in accept-language http field, then, it would look for english. Then, if there is neither english nor french, it would return the english version.
I don't forget to exclude the robots.txt from the redirection as it should be in root folder of the website.

```
RewriteEngine On
#exclude robots.txt 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} robots.txt
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://nicolasgueri.net/fr/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://nicolasgueri.net/en/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://nicolasgueri.net/en/ [L,R=301]
```