# how to redirect all languages but one to the English version of my page using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, multilingual

I have a system available in German and English and I'm trying to set `.htaccess` to redirect all languages NOT German to the English version of my site.

To test, I'm trying this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect non German to English site
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?Sprachwechsel=EN [R,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

which should forward to the English page, when the browser language is German. However, nothing happens.

**Question:**
I only know very basic `.htaccess` so is there something wrong with my snippet?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this: [Redirect based on Accept-Language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2888137/53114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a typo in your post, your line to check language is commented out in your posted code.

I haven't tested this, but it looks like you're really close, other then being commented out perhaps just missing the negation on german.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect non German to English site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?Sprachwechsel=EN [R,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ok. I will have a look. Also seems my `htaccess` is not working... hm.